# Update the database with new values after a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dbmigrate

I have a table in my database called `sessions` with two columns (`start_time` and `end_time`) in it and I already have lots of data in my table. I then generated a migration:

```
$ rails g migration AddDurationToSessions duration:integer
```

My model `session.rb` looks like this:

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_save :calc_duration

   def calc_duration
     return self[:end_time] - self[:start_time]
   end
end
```

My question is: how do I apply `calc_duration` to all of my older elements in my table? Do I update them manually or is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in migration:

```
class AddDurationToSessions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :sessions, :duration, :integer

    # Find and update all older session record
    Session.find_each do |s|
      # new duration
      calc_duration = s.end_time - s.start_time
      # update session with new duration
      s.update(duration: calc_duration.to_i)
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: After coding in Rails for more than a year, I've learned not yo use class methods in migrations, but SQL statements instead. The reason for this is because methods can change (after the migration was executed), thus make the migration unusable. Also read [this](http://jacopretorius.net/2014/07/patterns-for-data-migrations-in-rails.html).